# Add decelerating animation on rotating wheel view

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

How to add decelerating animation effect for wheel view rotation?

Currently I am following below source code for one finger rotation. 
https://github.com/kirbyt/KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this
https://github.com/rajendrahn/RotationWheelAndDecelerationBehaviour.
It has the rotating wheel with deceleration. Also it has separate class for deceleration behaviour so that it can be used with any view.